# Strongly Connected Graph is cyclic graph or not?

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory

I am fairly new to Graph theory and I have a a very basic  doubt regarding Strongly connected component of a graph. It says two nodes or more are strongly connected if there are paths from both nodes to each other.so whether this graph qualifies as  a cyclic graph with cycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, strongly connected graphs are cyclic. In such graphs any two vertices, say `u` and `v` are strongly connected, so there exists a path from `u` to `v` and a path from `v` to `u` made of directed edges. If the `u->v` path and the `v->u` path are disjoint, concatenate them and you have the cycle. If they share edges, start from `u` and follow the `u->v` path, once you hit the first edge shared by the two paths, start following the `v->u` path until you return to `u`.